# Print Oracle date without time stamp

Tags: php, html, oracle, date, timestamp

I am currently fetching dates from an oracle database, passing them to PHPs, where I print the data. The problem is the time-portion of the date has no use to me, and I don't want to print it. How can I exclude it?

I am having users input dates into a form, which updates the database. The PHP's pull the dates from the database using basic SQL currently. I can't seem to find anything that does this, but I probably am just not searching using the correct jargon :/ obvi I'm new to programming.

**I apologize that my code is not formatted with tabs, for some reason it isn't transferring over right, and won't let me space it out correctly.**

Example form:

```
    <form  method="post" action="UpdateInfo_AM.php">
       <u>As Of:</u> <input name="AM_updated" type="date" value= "mm/dd/yyyy><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

Example Handler:

```
    $AM_updated = $_POST['AM_updated'];
    $objConnect = oci_connect("user", "pass", "(description=(address=(protocol=tcp)(host=HOSTID.COM)(port=1533))(connect_data=(service_name=SID)))");
    $strSQL =  "UPDATE TABLENAME 
            SET 
            AM_UPDATED = '$AM_updated'";
    $objParse = oci_parse($objConnect, $strSQL);  
    $objExecute = oci_execute($objParse);
```

In another PHP, I define all variables as an array $row[].

Example print:

```
    <span style="font-size: 50px; font-weight: bold;">
   Metrics are accurate as of: <?php echo $row["AM_UPDATED"] ?>
</span>
```

Upon doing that, I get something like this:

```
Metrics are accurate as of: 12/12/2012 00:00:00
```

How can I exclude the 00:00:00?

Comment: Yes, the code would help. We can't magically read your mind and see what it's doing. Until you show your fetch/display code, we cannot help you. With the amount of info you've provided, the ONLY help we can give is: The code's until your control. If you don't want something to be printed, then don't print it

Comment: Okay, I will update OP momentarily! Thanks!

Comment: http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_char.php

Comment: Thanks, Marc! I appreciate the help. I'd up, but I don't have enough rep yet lol. Have a nice day!